# Python -- add new column that takes other column values into account to create the values for the new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I want to create a new column in my dataframe, let's call it "outcome". I want each value in "outcome" to be determined based off values in two other columns. So let's say this is my dataframe:

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
        'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
```

This is what out dataframe looks like:

```
  subject_id first_name last_name
0          1       Alex  Anderson
1          2        Amy  Ackerman
2          3      Allen       Ali
3          4      Alice      Aoni
4          5     Ayoung   Atiches
```

So I want to create a new column that kind of takes in logic like this:

```
if(df_a[df_a['subject_id'] == 2] & df_a[df_a['first_name'] == 'Amy']):
  df_a['outcome'] = 2
elif(df_a[df_a['subject_id'] > 0] & df_a[df_a['first_name'] == 'Alice']):
  df_a['outcome'] = 1
else:
  df_a['outcome'] = 0
```

I cannot seem to get it to work properly though. I expect the new column to look like this:

```
  subject_id first_name last_name outcome
0          1       Alex  Anderson   0
1          2        Amy  Ackerman   2
2          3      Allen       Ali   0
3          4      Alice      Aoni   1
4          5     Ayoung   Atiches   0
```

Comment: Use `np.where`? Or, `np.select`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ how do you use np.where with multiple conditions?

Comment: I'll show you..

Comment: `c1 = (df_a['subject_id'] == '2') & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Amy');
c2 = (df_a['subject_id'] > '0') & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Alice')` And, `np.where(c1, '2', np.where(c2, '1', '0')) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#first convert `subject_id` to int
df_a['subject_id'] = df_a['subject_id'].astype(int)
m1 = (df_a['subject_id'] == 2) & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Amy')
m2 = (df_a['subject_id'] > 0) & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Alice')

df_a['outcome'] = np.select([m1, m2], [2,1], default=0)
print (df_a)
   subject_id first_name last_name  outcome
0           1       Alex  Anderson        0
1           2        Amy  Ackerman        2
2           3      Allen       Ali        0
3           4      Alice      Aoni        1
4           5     Ayoung   Atiches        0
```

Or:

```
df_a['outcome'] = np.where(m1, 2, np.where(m2, 1, 0))
print (df_a)
   subject_id first_name last_name  outcome
0           1       Alex  Anderson        0
1           2        Amy  Ackerman        2
2           3      Allen       Ali        0
3           4      Alice      Aoni        1
4           5     Ayoung   Atiches        0
```

Comment: `subject_id` is a string... you're comparing ints. You'll get errors. I guess you didn't run your code?

Comment: Yes, I do it. only forget mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_a.loc[(df_a['subject_id'] == 2) & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Amy'),'outcome']=2
df_a.loc[(df_a['subject_id'] > 0 ) & (df_a['first_name'] == 'Alice'),'outcome']=1
df_a['outcome'].fillna(0)
```

Not as good as the above, but looking at what you were trying to do, this will be relevant for you.